# Как загрузить файл к задаче в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нашел код, который выполняет данную задачу:

```
if (CModule::IncludeModule('disk') && CModule::IncludeModule('tasks')){

        $oTask = new CTaskItem($task_id, $user_id);
        $arFields = array(
            "UF_TASK_WEBDAV_FILES"   => array("n".$disk_file_id)
        );
        try
        {
            if ( ! $oTask->update($arFields) )
                throw new TasksException();
        }
        catch (TasksException $e)
        {
            print_r($e);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Но не могу понять, что подставить в переменную $disk_file_id.

Comment: ну по названию переменной вроде бы понятно что она содержит ID файла в диске Bitrix если посмотреть в документации https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/tasks/classes/ctaskitem/update.php там в низу есть пример с кодом в котором все понятно расписано что к чему

Comment: "Class 'Bitrix\Disk\Driver' not found", вероятно для моей версии не работает (14), хотя в доках не нашел номер версии, с какой работает

Comment: В доке написано, что с версии 16 Странно в 2018 году использовать 14 версию.

Answer (score 0):

CFile::MakeFileArray(reset($rsFile))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]